# Are the websites hosted on Github restricted to programming?

Tags: web-hosting, static-content, github

I was searching about static hosting and I found blog posts talking about hosting their blog on Github, the hosting feature of Github seems pretty good, what I want to know is what type of websites can we host on Github pages ? should all the hosted websites be related somehow to programming (open source) or personal Github users pages (CV, Blog, Repositories).

I'm aware that we can host only static websites and the repository will be public, I searched the terms of service and searched on the [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com/) page and I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant help page:  https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages  They have two types of pages: **User/Organization Pages** and **Project Pages**

Based on this, they are not limiting the use of Github Pages to just software projects.  They allow pages for users and organizations.

Comment: Yeah I know about the pages for users/organizations or projects, but for example on the [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) site at the bottom you can see **Free hosting with GitHub Pages, Sick of dealing with hosting companies? GitHub Pages are powered by Jekyll, so you can easily deploy your site using GitHub for free—custom domain name and all.**

Does this mean we can host any website on Github as long as it is static regardless of what it is about ? I couldn't find any info about this, maybe I'll contact their support.

Comment: @Peter Anything legal can be used for GH Pages. Even GH isn't just for code, it is used by designers & all sorts of people.